# Express-js wildcard routing to cover everything under and including a path

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to have one route cover everything under `/foo` including `/foo` itself. I've tried using `/foo*` which work for everything *except* it doesn't match `/foo`. Observe:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express.createServer();

app.get("/foo*", function(req, res, next){
  res.write("Foo*\n");
  next();
});

app.get("/foo", function(req, res){
  res.end("Foo\n");
});

app.get("/foo/bar", function(req, res){
  res.end("Foo Bar\n");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Outputs:

```
$ curl localhost:3000/foo
Foo
$ curl localhost:3000/foo/bar
Foo*
Foo Bar
```

What are my options? The best I've come up with is to route `/fo*` which of course isn't very optimal as it would match way too much.

Comment: If your intercepting all `/foo*` routes like that don't you want to make it middleware instead?

Comment: Be careful what you ask for:  `/foo*` matches `/foo/bar` but also matches `/foolish` which you probably didn't intend.

Comment: Which version of Express is this? `foo*` will match `foo` in recent versions, so (as far as I can tell) this is basically no longer an issue except for legacy projects as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18702690/6243352) indicates.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I think you will have to have 2 routes. If you look at line 331 of the connect router the * in a path is replaced with .+ so will match 1 or more characters.

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/router.js

If you have 2 routes that perform the same action you can do the following to keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express.createServer();

function fooRoute(req, res, next) {
  res.end("Foo Route\n");
}

app.get("/foo*", fooRoute);
app.get("/foo", fooRoute);

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: `app.get(["/foo", "/foo*"], /* function */);` might be preferential as well!

Comment: Passing in an array of strings is preferential to me as well.  Unfortunately: passing an array to app.VERB() is deprecated and will be removed in 4.0

Comment: Passing in an array of strings has been restored in Express 4.9.1.

Answer (score 31):

The connect router has now been removed (https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/262), the author stating that you should use a framework on top of connect (like Express) for routing.

Express [currently treats](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/9e406dfee22f172c084c900e235e1ac7e9497a24/lib/utils.js#L312) `app.get("/foo*")` as `app.get(/\/foo(.*)/)`, removing the need for two separate routes.  This is in contrast to the previous answer (referring to the now removed connect router) which stated that "`*` in a path is replaced with `.+`".

**Update:** Express now uses the "path-to-regexp" module (since Express 4.0.0) which maintains [the same behavior](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/blob/v0.1.3/index.js#L64) in the version currently referenced. It's unclear to me whether the latest version of that module keeps the behavior, but for now this answer stands.

Comment: So should we use .+ or *?

Comment: Use `/\/foo(.+)/` if you want to match `/foo` followed by one or more characters, and `/foo*` or `/\/foo(.*)/` if you want to match `/foo` followed by zero or more characters.

Comment: "in the version currently referenced" is super vague, as is "now". This answer is super confusing.

Answer (score 20):

> It is not necessary to have two routes.
>
> Simply add `(/*)?` at the end of your `path` string.
>
> For example, **`app.get('/hello/world(/*)?' /* ... */)`**

Here is a fully working example, feel free to copy and paste this into a .js file to run with node, and play with it in a browser (or curl):

```js
const app = require('express')()

// will be able to match all of the following
const test1 = 'http://localhost:3000/hello/world'
const test2 = 'http://localhost:3000/hello/world/'
const test3 = 'http://localhost:3000/hello/world/with/more/stuff'

// but fail at this one
const failTest = 'http://localhost:3000/foo/world'

app.get('/hello/world(/*)?', (req, res) => res.send(`
    This will match at example endpoints: <br><br>
    <pre><a href="${test1}">${test1}</a></pre>
    <pre><a href="${test2}">${test2}</a></pre>
    <pre><a href="${test3}">${test3}</a></pre>

    <br><br> Will NOT match at: <pre><a href="${failTest}">${failTest}</a></pre>
`))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Check this out in a browser at http://localhost:3000/hello/world!'))
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it didn't work for me. 
middleware: `/template/:id(/*)?` 
parent dir: `/template/:id` 
sub dir: `/template/:id/edit` 
both directories will trigger as expected but middleware won't trigger at all

Comment: Found it out... middleware `router.use('/template/:id', ...)` will work perfectly

Answer (score 14):

In array you also can use variables passing to req.params:

```
app.get(["/:foo", "/:foo/:bar"], /* function */);
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are learning node/express (just like me): do not use wildcard routing if possible!

I also wanted to implement the routing for GET /users/:id/whatever using wildcard routing. This is how I got here.

More info: https://blog.praveen.science/wildcard-routing-is-an-anti-pattern/

Comment: Link currently dead. Perhaps it was same as: https://jonathanong.github.io/wildcard-routing-is-an-anti-pattern.html

Comment: @RonBurk your url seems to be dead also.. How can I have optional wildcard *after* a named parameter? "/something/:id(/*)?" doesn't work..

Comment: Probably will still be in Google cache for a little while: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:E4WmY97yWqQJ:https://jonathanong.github.io/wildcard-routing-is-an-anti-pattern.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1-d

Comment: is there an alternative to wildcard routing if I have no idea what comes after the initial part of the URL?

Comment: @RonBurk Even that's dead... 

Comment: Here's the republished one: [Wildcard Routing is an Anti-Pattern](https://blog.praveen.science/wildcard-routing-is-an-anti-pattern/)

Comment: When proxying an API, wildcard routing is decidedly NOT an anti-pattern. The article seems to start with the assumption and then find edge cases to support it.