# Redirect to ''/'' in Node.js + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I created a project on Node.js + AngularJS I have routes in this project. How I can create redirect  to '/' if the user prints whatever link in searching panel.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular 2/4/5?

Comment: *user prints whatever link in searching panel.*? Could you expand on what you've tried and what you want to do?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I use Angular 1.6

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to use [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) as nodeJS framework but via nodeJS you can use the router library to acheive the same.

```
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler')
var http         = require('http')
var Router       = require('router')

var router = Router();

//other route urls here

//have this at the end
router.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
  res.end('Hello World!');
  //or write you logic here.
})

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  router(req, res, finalhandler(req, res))
})

server.listen(3000)
```

Read in detail about the [Router Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/router)

Also [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161675/7260635)