# Angular 4 remove hash(#) from url

Tags: angular, angular4-router

my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
.......
  providers: [
....
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
....
]
});
```

when i remove this part, it's works in my localhost but after taking a **ng build**  or **ng build --prod** , when i refresh the page or h5 it doesn't work. It gives 404 error. **I want to remove hash(#) from my url**. Any solution ?

Answer (score 12):

You can check [the angular guide about deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

Let's talk about the difference between `HashLocationStrategy` and `PathLocationStrategy`. For more info, [check the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Angular, by default, uses `PathLocationStrategy`.

Let's say you have following routes in your application.

```
const routes: Route[] = [{
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'home',
   pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
   path: 'home',
   component: HomeComponent
}];
```

When you route to this component, your address bar will look like `localhost:4200/home`. If you used `HashLocationStrategy`, it would look like `localhost:4200/#home`. So, what's the difference here?

- `PathLocationStrategy`

  When you are on page `Home` and hit `F5` button or refresh the page, the browser will make a request to `localhost:4200/home` which will handled by angular-cli and you'll have your `HomeComponent` returned.
- `HashLocationStrategy`

  Likewise, when you hit `F5`, the browser will make the request to `localhost:4200` this time, because it ignores whatever comes after `#`

If you don't want to have `#`, then remove the part you pointed out. It'll be `PathLocationStrategy` by default. However, this brings us to part when you run your application outside of `angular-cli` which means building and serving it from some server. Let's say you build your application with `ng build` and you have your minified, compiled javascript files. You deploy it to some server which runs on `yourdomain.com`

Also, you put this built, bundled angular application at some url so that people will access your application from `yourdomain.com/ng-app`, everything is fine here. Even, when you route to `HomeComponent`, it'll work and your address bar will look like `yourdomain.com/ng-app/home`. However, when you hit `F5` at this point, your browser will make request to `yourdomain.com/ng-app/home` which does not exist on your server because you serve your application from `/ng-app`. You have to do some config at your server side so that you can serve everything that starts with `/ng-app/**`.

For example, my spring application has this method that returns the angular application,

```
@GetMapping("/ng-app/**")
```

So when my server gets a request that starts with `/ng-app`, it just passes this to angular application which will handle the correct route.

Hope, this clarifies it for you.

Comment: Okay, so from what I gathered, using Path Location strategy will result in the removal of the hashtag but will make a call to the non-existent path in the server, and using the method

`@RequestMapping(value = "/ng-app/**", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })`

Would help me achieve that, right?

Comment: Exactly. Do you use spring for backend?

Comment: No.. i use node.js  & express

Comment: I don't know how to do that in express, but there must be a way to do what I suggested in the answer.

Comment: Right, if I were to search this would "NodeJS RequestMappings" suffice?

Comment: RequestMapping is a spring annotation. I wouldn't know it's equivalence in nodejs. But, it may be similar.

Comment: Check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161567/express-js-wildcard-routing-to-cover-everything-under-and-including-a-path

Comment: @Brunyamin  sure

Comment: Yes, It worked in my env. But when I am rendering index.html into another page which uses iframe then # again returned.like <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Test Header</h1>
</div>
<iframe style="width:100%;height:870px" src="index.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite the URL rules.For every server rules will be diifferent and you can try this for IIS.

=> Create web.config in src folder and copy below code.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <configuration>

        <system.webServer>
          <rewrite>
            <rules>
              <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
                     negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
                    negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>

        </configuration>
```

=> add web.config path to angular-cli.json file:

```
    "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "web.config"
    ],
```

=> Let’s build: ng build --prod