# URI not accessible after build in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular app. Everything is working fine during development, but after build,  i encountered the errors as describe below:

I have a route to '/profile'

If i hit the url directly, it show "No input file specified." on my homestead and show "500 internal server error" on the production server

BUT if I navigate to the url by clicking on a link, it works well and show the '/profile' page well.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';

export const PagesRoutes: Routes = [
   {
      path: 'profile',
      component: ProfileComponent
    }];
```

I dont really know where the problem could be coming from. It works well during development

Comment: What's your server running on? What kind of application is it?

Comment: Accessing the path `/profile` won't work because the application is not loaded yet, you need to edit `.htaccess` to redirect any path to `/index.html`

Comment: and by the way it should return `404` not `500` on production, unless it's using some `index.php` and that is causing the `500` error

Comment: As @Hussein suggested, you need to forward all of the requests coming to a certain URI to angular application. This was a different question but I mentioned the problem you are having in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022951/angular-4-remove-hash-from-url/49023187#49023187

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner am am accessing the build app 
nginx version: nginx/1.15.5

Comment: @Hussein what whould i edit in .htaccess ?

Comment: You need to redirect all of the requests to angular application. Do you have some sort of context-root for your angular application?

Comment: Please how do I do that? in your answer posted in the link you shared, you said something about @GetMapping("/ng-app/**")  where do i add this?

Comment: Add this line `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` in `.htaccess` file

Comment: I think this is what i need 
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: Thanks guys i got it working by editing the .htaccess in my Apache production server.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by editing the `.htaccess` as suggested by @Hussein

Add this line `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` in `.htaccess` file