# 404 when refreshing page on github pages with Angular 6 app

Tags: angular, github

Following the docs on : https://angular.io/guide/deployment

I did :

```
ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href https://v2.kendozone.com
```

and it worked, but each time I refreshed the page, https://v2.kendozone.com/ was changing into https://v2.kendozone.com/login which is normal, and if I refresh the page, I get a 404.

Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upps, my problem was not reading the doc til the end.

On the bottom of the angular doc, it says you have to create a copy of index.html and rename it 404.html, so that when it doesn't find the page, it goes on 404.

Comment: Check this question out --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022951/angular-4-remove-hash-from-url/49023187?r=SearchResults#49023187

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and fixed it using hash:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]
```

Reference:

https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

Answer (score -1):

To properly handle `not found` events, you just have to put that at the end of your router definitions:

```
 {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
```

And define `NotFoundComponent` of course. "At the end", because `**` will match any route that didn't match anything so far.

By defining `404.html` yourself, I guess you use the default Angular router for 404.