# Angular 8 Routing: Changing URL doesn't navigate to expected page

Tags: angular, browser, url-routing

I'm creating a simple Angular project with two components: **home** and **submit**. My **app-routing.module.ts** look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SubmitComponent } from './submit/submit.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'submit', component: SubmitComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In my browser if I change the path to */submit* the page looks like it reloads and then defaults back to */home*. I have already tried changing the **path: ''** to **path: '**'**. It does not navigate to the **submit** component. Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

Angular 8.2.14
Google Chrome

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: No. Only normal Angular stuff

Comment: Do you have `<base href="/">` added in your index.html head?

Comment: Yes. I do have that in the index.html

Comment: how does your app-routing module look? Please share some more details.

Comment: I will update my initial post to contain the entire file.

Comment: you should be able to navigate to `/#/submit`,make sure to use right url and pathMatch:full for other routes too

Comment: Okay, it does let me navigate to /#/submit. But how do I get rid of the '#'. I don't want my users to have to type that in if they want to go to the submit page

Comment: I just want to be able to type is 'www.website.com/submit' and it take them there

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

Comment: Where exactly do I put that? I'm sorry. I'm new to Angular. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The default client-side routing strategy used in Angular is the `PathLocationStrategy` so it should work for you. Unless you are setting `{useHash:true}` in your app. Check this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023187/9386929

And the LocationStrategy needs to be added to app.module.ts, `providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],`

Comment: Okay, I will look into that! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your routing configuration. We don't have enough information to help you pinpoint your issue beyond that.

When I am approached with this question, it's usually one of the following problems:

1. Missing `<base href="/">` in your index.html `head` element
2. Not importing AppRoutingModule into your AppModule
3. Missing
   `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` element in parent component

I saw in the comments that you have the `<base href="/">` in your index.html file so we'll forget that one for now.

From here:

Check to make sure you're importing your `AppRoutingModule` in your App.Module.ts file.

If that's not the issue, make sure you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` element in your parent component (probably your app.component.html based on the simplicity of your app). The Angular router searches your routes for one that matches the URI and injects an instance of the component specified in your routing configuration into the closest `router-outlet` that is higher up in the component tree. In other words, if there is no `router-outlet`, the Angular router doesn't know where to render the component you specified in your routing configuration.

If neither of those solve your problem, try posting more information so we can help further. It would be helpful to see your app.module.ts and app.component.html files at a minimum. Alternatively, try recreating your app in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and posting the link.