# 404 error on node.js proxy to api when I deploy to Heroku

Tags: json, node.js, rest, heroku

I created `proxy.config.json`:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://myappapi.herokuapp.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

When i call `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json --open` it works fine.

Now, to run on Heroku.

I created `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');
var herokuProxy = require('heroku-proxy');

const app = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

app.use(express.static('./dist/mywebapp'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/mywebapp/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
    console.log('Server started');
})

app.use(herokuProxy({
    hostname: 'myappapi.herokuapp.com',
    prefix: ''
}));
```

I change package.json

```
"start": "ng serve",
```

to

```
"start": "node index.js",
```

and typed:

```
npm install
```

and

```
heroku local web
```

This is the error that i see on console:

```
> "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">
> <title>Error</title> </head> <body> 
> <pre>Cannot GET /api/question/</pre>
> </body> </html> "
```

and this is the message:

> "Http failure response for
>   http://localhost:5000/api/question/?format=json: 404 Not Found"

Comment: Hey Luciano! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some details on what you are trying to achieve. My immediate suggestion would be to see what is trying to call `api/question`.

Comment: This is because /api/question route is not defined. You need to set up this route to be able to access it. `app.get('/api/question/...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161567/express-js-wildcard-routing-to-cover-everything-under-and-including-a-path  accepted ans there explains use of wildcards which may be needed in this case in addition to just '/'  as route for all wildcards covered by api details

Comment: @cameck /api/question should point to host http://myappapi.herokuapp.com/api/question. The service is there.

Comment: @itaintme /api/question should point to host http://myappapi.herokuapp.com/api/question. The service is there.

Comment: @Luciano Sena You have set prefix to `''` which overrides the default `api`

Comment: @itaintme yes.

app.use(herokuProxy({
    hostname: '<myapi>.herokuapp.com',
    prefix: '',
    protocol: 'https',
    log: true
}));

Comment: I solved. I will post the solution ASAP.

Comment: @LucianoSena Do you happen to have this solution