# What does "/*" mean in node / express app.get("/*)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was wondering if someone can clarify what the "/*" path means in express / nodejs.

In my code i wrote the following to get the path of React Router pages on my application:

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

This worked, but would not if i did not use the *. I know that "/" is the root, and I assume the * has something to do with getting different routes but I can not find an explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: * is a wild card token. it means match any top level route eg `/foo` or `/foo-bar-1` or `/a` etc

Comment: `*` in almost all file path situations is a ["glob"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), meaning it matches anything.

Comment: See also [Express-js wildcard routing to cover everything under and including a path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6161567/215552)

Comment: Did you read https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html?

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a wild card. This means this router will handle not just `/`, but any request that starts with `/` - be it `/mokate`, `/stackoverflow`, or even `/easter-bunny`.

Comment: Thank you very much!