# How to implement nextjs catch all routes functionality in pure express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, next.js

in nextjs, there is a way to **catch all path parameters to an array of slugs**.

e.g `pages/post/[...slug].js` matches /post/a, but also /post/a/b, /post/a/b/c and etc.
and the req.params will be `{ "slug": ["a", "b"] }`.

how can I handle all dynamic path parameters into one [...params] route. for example `/api/products/[...categories]` will match `/api/products/plates` or `/api/products/plates/cups` and req.params will be `{categories: ["plates", "cups"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express-js wildcard routing to cover everything under and including a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161567/express-js-wildcard-routing-to-cover-everything-under-and-including-a-path)

Comment: the method you mentioned is only for routing and not allowing to extract params.

Comment: You can extract the params from the `req` object.